# C# Multi line and multi column email reader extractor

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

So I have made a console application in C# that will read emails and extract the data from it.

With some help I have got it to a stage where it can read columns in pairs but as soon as I hit the bottom of the email (There could be even more lines than these two) it fails to break it down.

This is what I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Multiline_Email_Test
{
// <summary>
/// Console app to test the reading of the multiline email.
/// If successful readback is shown we could import to SQL Server.
/// </summary>
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string email = @"NOTIFICATION OF MOVEMENT STARTING IN AUGUST

Consignor Package ID                              Local Reference Number
-------------------                              ----------------------
GRLK123450012                                         123456

Place Of dispatch                                Guarantor type code
-----------------                                -------------------
GR00001234567                                          1

Consignee Package ID                              Guarantor details
-----------------                                -------------------
RR001239E0070

Place Of delivery                                Date of dispatch DD MM YYYY
-----------------                                ---------------------------
FR001379E0570                                    21 03 2019

                                                 Time of dispatch
                                                 ----------------
                                                 08:29

                                                Vehicle registration number
                                               ---------------------------
                                               XXBB12345678

Item number   Package Product CN CodeCode    Quantity       Brand
-----------   -------------------------     --------       -----
Line 1 of 2   B000           22040009       7603.200       Guinness DIC    440ml CAN 06X04 MDCES
Line 2 of 2   B000           22040009       14636.160      Guinness DIC    440ml CAN 06X04 MDCES

";



var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try
        {
            var lines = email.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int starts = 0, end = 0, length = 0;
            while (!lines[starts + 1].StartsWith("-"))
                starts++;
            for (int i = starts + 1; i < lines.Length; i += 3)
            {
                var mc = Regex.Matches(lines[i], @"(?:^| )-");
                foreach (Match m in mc)
                {
                    int start = m.Value.StartsWith(" ") ? m.Index + 1 : m.Index;
                    end = start;
                    while (lines[i][end++] == '-' && end < lines[i].Length)
                        ;
                    length = Math.Min(end - start, lines[i - 1].Length - start);
                    string key = length > 0 ? lines[i - 1].Substring(start, length).Trim() : "";
                    end = start;
                    while (lines[i][end++] == '-' && end < lines[i].Length)
                        ;
                    length = Math.Min(end - start, lines[i + 1].Length - start);
                    string value = length > 0 ? lines[i + 1].Substring(start, length).Trim() : "";
                    dict.Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var x in dict)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", x.Key, x.Value);
       }
   }
}
```

I have created a live demo in .net fiddle here
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6nMO2c

Comment: Your code does exactly what you ask it to. You only read values that are below a dashed line and the bottom line isn't, so it's not read. If you want to make sense of this email, you need a different strategy.

Comment: How would I get it to Match "Item Number" and the process the reading of the six columns differently?

Comment: I think more information is needed. Would it be possible to read fixed columns? The headers and dashed lines don't fit anyway. The "Bran" is harshly truncated and the coli (I presume it is) column is not present in the header.

Comment: Sure, the headers can move so fixed columns are not possible, there is truncation and movement from left to right if data is longer which is why I thought Regex Match would find it regardless.

Comment: NB. Are you sure a `Dictionary<string, string>` is the right data structure here? Won't data from the first item line be overwritten with data from the second? Maybe consider a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`?

Comment: I still need the headers from the columns

Comment: Perhaps I can try a new approach to serialize the data first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the header values of the document, your code seems to be functional, but just for fun, I found a regex that does the job.
Then I also answer the question about the table data.

```
        int textArrayPosition = 0; // Just to separate the header part and the table part
        var headersDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        List<string> arrayHeaders;
        List<List<string>> arrayData = new List<List<string>>();
        var headersFinder = new Regex(@"^(.*?) {2,}(.*)\r\n\-*? {2,}\-*\r\n(.*?)( {2,}(.*)|$)", RegexOptions.Multiline);

        foreach (Match match in headersFinder.Matches(inputText))
        {
            if (match.Groups.Count < 4)
                continue;

            var firstHeaderName = match.Groups[1].Value;
            var secondHeaderName = match.Groups[2].Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstHeaderName))
                headersDictionary.Add(firstHeaderName, match.Groups[3].Value);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secondHeaderName))
            {
                if (match.Groups.Count == 6)
                    headersDictionary.Add(secondHeaderName, match.Groups[5].Value);
                else
                    headersDictionary.Add(secondHeaderName, string.Empty);
            }

            textArrayPosition = match.Index + match.Length;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*** Document headers :");
        foreach (var entry in headersDictionary)
            Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key} = {entry.Value}");
```

Then, we find the table in your text as a list of lines.

```
 var arrayLines = inputText.Substring(textArrayPosition).Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Thus, we treat the table: as the headers of the table do not allow to separate the columns, I based myself on the fact of finding at least 2 consecutive spaces in the first line of data to be able to guess the positions of the columns. A simple regex helps us to do that.

```
        if (arrayLines.Length > 2)
        {
            var arrayColsPositions = new List<int>();

            // Find cols positions
            arrayColsPositions.Add(0);
            var firstDataLine = arrayLines[2];
            var columnsPositionDetector = new Regex(@" {2,}", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match match in columnsPositionDetector.Matches(firstDataLine))
            {
                arrayColsPositions.Add(match.Index + match.Length);
            }

            // Find headers
            arrayHeaders = ReadLineValues(arrayLines[0], arrayColsPositions).ToList();
            // Find data lines
            for (int lineId = 2; lineId < arrayLines.Length; lineId++)
            {
                arrayData.Add(ReadLineValues(arrayLines[lineId], arrayColsPositions).ToList());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n*** Array headers :");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arrayHeaders));

            Console.WriteLine("\n*** Array lines data :");
            foreach (var record in arrayData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", record));
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("The array is empty.");
```

Finally, here is the little utility method that I developed to search nicely, without exceeding the lengths of certain lines, for the data in the right place.

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLineValues(string sourceLine, List<int> colsPositions)
    {
        for (int colId = 0; colId < colsPositions.Count; colId++)
        {
            var start = colsPositions[colId];
            int length;
            if (colId < colsPositions.Count - 1)
                length = colsPositions[colId + 1] - start;
            else
                length = sourceLine.Length - start;

            if (start < sourceLine.Length)
            {
                if (start + length > sourceLine.Length)
                    length = sourceLine.Length - start;

                yield return sourceLine.Substring(start, length).Trim();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the Regex and Substring method line by line to split into two columns until it hits Item number as a keyword and trim and white spaces from each, with plenty of conditional if's, though I will also try this out